# Cannot read property 'createKeywordTypeNode' of undefined

Tags: reactjs, typescript, relayjs, relay, react-relay

I have a react typescript application which uses GraphQl. Everything was working fine till yesterday
But now I am receiving a weird bug while executing the command  `"yarn run relay && react-scripts start"`

`"relay": "relay-compiler --src ./src --schema ./src/modules/open-cti/schema.graphql --language=typescript --extensions=ts --extensions=tsx",`

Can anyone help how to troubleshoot this one
I am using `nodejs 12.16.1` and Typescript version `^3.8.3`

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was because they deprecated the typescript API usages and merged it to the minor version . A patch will be available soon. In the meantime you could pin down the previous version. or upgrade your project to typescript 4.
https://github.com/relay-tools/relay-compiler-language-typescript/issues/272